# How do you read the complete Fulfillment/Rejection value in Ember's Chrome Addon?

Tags: ember.js

My Ember app compiles fine however displays nothing in the browser.  The Ember Chrome Addon shows a lot of the following messages in the Promises section:

`Error: Could not find module 'e...       > Stack trace`

How do you get the name of the module in question above?

Answer (score 1):

The `> Stack trace` is a clickable link that will dump the contents into the browser's console.

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/wiki/Promises-Tab#understanding-the-ui for more info.